# Is it possible to execute «unless» clause as a specific user?

Tags: puppet

#### Background:

I am upgrading our `lxc` puppet module to support the emerging unprivileged LXC technology.

The code that creates the container is executed unless the following test if the container exists succeeds: `lxc-info -n ${lxcname} >/dev/null`. If executed as root, the `lxc-info` checks for the name among the root containers. If invoked by a normal user, it checks against the list of unprivileged containers stored for this particular user.

I want to create a resource along the lines of (code not tested yet):

```
#Creation of the container ${name}
  exec { "lxc-create of ${hostname}":
    command => "lxc-create -t download -n ${name} -- -d ubuntu -r ${release} -a amd64",
    user    => $user,
    group   => $group,
    timeout => 0,
    unless  => "lxc-info -n ${name}" #Should be executed as user ${user}, not root!
  }
```

I can fix this problem if I change the last parameter to

```
unless  => "su -l ${user} -c 'lxc-info -n ${name}'"
```

but it just don't look elegant. Is there any built-in solution in puppet to make a check as other user?

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce with `2.7.22` or `3.7.3`. I don't have LXC, but did a simple test: `puppet apply -e 'exec { "/bin/cat /root/test": user => "nobody", onlyif => "/usr/bin/test -r /root/test" }'`. As expected, it will not try to sync the `exec` if run as non-root. Apparently, the `user` parameter does apply to the `onlyif` parameter. A reverse test indicates that `unless` behaves the same way.

Comment: @FelixFrank Thank you. I actually assumed, that it gets executed by root, since the documentation never mentions otherwise. I'll confirm it soon.

Comment: Wait what, you haven't even tried but asked the question based on an assumption?

Comment: @FelixFrank Yes. I admit to being lazy. Shame on me. IMHO The documentation should be more accurate though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix said, the unless uses the same user as the main command.

From [the documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-unless):

> **unless**
>
> ...
>   Note that this command follows the same rules as the main command

This has now been clarified in the documentation: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/3800/files